# Auto scroll navbar lists when mouse reach the end

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying something in which the nav list items scrolls horizontally automatically when the mouse cursor reaches the end of the screen.

This is my index page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@600&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>mr.SoSerious - Web Developer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="nav_container">
        <a href="about.html" class="nav_link w-inline-block">
          <div class="nav_label">ABOUT</div>
        </a>
        <link rel="prefetch" href="about.html" />
        <div class="nav_dash"></div>
        <a href="projects.html" class="nav_link w-inline-block">
          <div class="nav_label">PROJECTS</div>
        </a>
        <link rel="prefetch" href="projects.html" />
        <div class="nav_dash"></div>
        <a href="contact.html" class="nav_link w-inline-block">
          <div class="nav_label">CONTACT</div>
        </a>
        <link rel="prefetch" href="contact.html" />
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

This is the css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(44, 42, 42);
}

.footer_link,
.header,
.nav_link {
  color: #2c2a2a;
}

.nav_link,
.sidebar_trigger {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  -ms-grid-row-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.nav_link {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 1vw;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_label {
  -webkit-transition: letter-spacing 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  transition: letter-spacing 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  font-size: 12vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -0.03em;
  color: #707070;
}

.nav_label:hover {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: white;
}

.nav_dash {
  width: 4vw;
  height: 2px;
  margin-right: 5vw;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  background-color: #acb1a1;
}

.nav {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav_container {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
```

And here is the output:
What I need is that when the pointer reaches near the screen, the list scrolls horizontally to reveal more list items.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by pointer and mouse cursor?  Is your target audience desktop computers?  Say reaches near the screen another way.  Near the right or left edge of the screen maybe?  Why did you use the word lists in the title?  It makes html developers think that you're using li elements.

Comment: with javascript, you could use mouse position and scroll position, etc, and DOM properties of the elements like clientWidth, offsetWidth, etc. How you set up your page depends on what particular code you'd use. You'd be doing some simple calculation to test if the mouse position is in range of your window edge. Some tricks could involve wrapping everything in a 100% width container to make some of it simpler.

Comment: Also, I'm sure similar answers already exist if you search for mouse position, element position, scroll position, etc.